# My program immediately exits shortly after completing the first scanf prompt

Tags: arrays, c, windows, scanf, action

I'm still relatively new to C despite my experience in C++. I'm writing a program that takes a user-inputted array length and action variable, and I'm trying to accomplish this through the scanf prompt. I'm not sure if it's because of the way I have it set up, but my program has a short delay before shutting down after inputting my value for the array length. I'm assuming that the delay is the program reading and skipping through all the other lines in my code.

Here's the code I have right now. There are probably other issues, but I won't be able to check until my inputs are fixed.

```
// Input: The first line of the input contains an integer N and t (3 <= N <= 200000; 1 <= t <= 7)
// Output: For each test case, output the required answer based on the value of t.

#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    // Initialize integer N and t for inputting.
    int N, t;
    
    scanf("%d", N);
    scanf("%d", t);
    
    // Initialize array for inputting components.
    int A[N];
    for(int c = 0; c < N; c++){
        scanf("%d", A[c]);
    }
    
    switch(t){
        // Print 7, regardless of array A's contents
        case 1:
            printf("%d\n, 7");
        
        // Print "Bigger" if A[0] > A[1] or "Equal" if A[0] == A[1]. Otherwise, print "Smaller".
        case 2:
            if(A[0] > A[1]){
                printf("%d\n, Bigger");
            }
            else if(A[0] == A[1]){
                printf("%d\n, Equal");
            }
            else{
                printf("%d\n, Smaller");
            }
        
        // Print the median of the first three indexes of the A array.
        case 3: 
            printf("%d\n, (A[0]+A[1]+A[2])/2");
        
        // Print the sum of all integers in A.
        case 4:
            printf("%d\n, Sum(A, N)");
        
        // Print the sum of all EVEN integers in A.
        case 5:
            printf("%d\n, evSum(A, N)");
        
        // Apply %26 to each integer in the A array, map integers from 0-25 to the alphabet,
            // and print the new sequence of characters as a string.
        case 6:
            // Figuring this one out
            printf("\nStub");
        
        // Start from index i = 0; Jump to index i = A[i]; If the current index is outside
            // the valid bound from 0 to N-1, print "Out" and exit. Else, if the
            // current index is the index N-1, print "Done" and exit, otherwise go back
            // to step b. If doing this leads to an infinite loop, print "Cyclic" and exit.
        case 7:
            // Figuring this one out
            printf("\nStub");
    }
    
    return 0;
}

// Integer function that returns the sum of all the integers in the inputted array.
// Apparently, you also need to add the length of the array externally, since it wont just let me use 'N'.
int sum(int* array[], int arrayLength){
    int k = 0;
    for(int o = 0; o < arrayLength; o++){
        k = k + *array[o];
    }
    return k;
}

// Integer function that returns the sum of all the even integers in the inputted array.
// To check if an integer is even, it checks if the modulo of 2 for the integer is equal to 0.
// Apparently, you also need to add the length of the array externally, since it wont just let me use 'N'.
int evSum(int* array[], int arrayLength){
    int l = 0;
    for(int m = 0; m < arrayLength; m++){
        if(*array[m] % 2 == 0){
            l = l + *array[m];
        }
    return l;
    }
}
```

I was expecting to at least be able to check through my code to make sure my sum functions were working fine before working on figuring out my 6th and 7th case

Comment: `scanf("%d"` requires an `int*`as an argument but you give it an `int`. That is, `scanf("%d", N);` should be `scanf("%d", &N);` etc.

Comment: `scanf()` requires you to provide the *addresses* of the objects in which to store converted inputs.  E.g. `scanf("%d", &N);`.

Comment: `printf("%d\n, 7");` is UB (undefined behavior). From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf#Parameters): *"If any argument after default argument promotions is not the type expected by the corresponding conversion specifier, or if there are fewer arguments than required by format, the behavior is undefined. If there are more arguments than required by format, the extraneous arguments are evaluated and ignored."*

Comment: ... that is, you appear to have meant `printf("%d\n", 7);`, instead.  There are several more like that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah that is probably OPs intention. However with the following `printf`s, OP is still using `%d` but also string literals. Either replace the `%d` with `%s`, or better just write it inline as `printf("Bigger\n");` etc.

Comment: "`printf("%d\n, 7");`" Your compiler should be complaining.  My gcc says `warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments`

Comment: You should get compiler warnings for these errors. Don't ignore warnings from the compiler. If you did not get any warning, turn up diagnostics level

Comment: It doesn't complete the first `scanf`. The very first `scanf("%d", N);` is undefined behavior. Your best remedy is to enable compiler warnings and read the man page for every library function you use. It's a steep learning curve. Write one line at a time, and test it works before you write the next line. It *is* a steep learning  curve but writing too much code at once makes it even harder.

Comment: Always compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and preferably also `-Werror`

Answer (score 1):

Your program invokes undefined behaviour as you pass the value of an initialized variable instead of the reference to it.

Also, you need to check if `scanf` did fail:

```
    int N, t;
    
    if(scanf("%d", &N) != 1) {/* handle error */}
    if(scanf("%d", &t) != 1) {/* handle error */}
```

also `printf("%d\n, 7");` is expecting a parameter after the format (but I think it is a typo [repeated in many other places] as you have a comma here).

```
printf("%d\n", 7);

/* or simple*/

printf("7\n");
```

same in many other places:

```
                printf("Bigger\n");

                printf("Equal\n");

                printf("Smaller\n");

            printf("%d\n", (A[0]+A[1]+A[2])/2);

            printf("%d\n", Sum(A, N));

            printf("%d\n", evSum(A, N));
```

(I could possibly miss more)

When compiling add `"-Wall -Wextra -Werror"` to the GCC command line and your code will not compile until you sort out similar problems